# Android Turnbased Multiplayer, accessing Chat functionality

Tags: android, google-play-games

I would like to implement a chat function in my turnbased multiplayer, yet there are some issues to doing this...

Namely, only one player has a turn at any one time, so another user couldn't send a message via the turnbased functionality. If I use Google Cloud Messaging, then I seem to need an email address for the player, but I can't see a way to get this if the player is not in my circle (e.g. a Quick Match is active).

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: If you are doing `Auto-matched players` game, the auto-matched players do not need to be in each other's Google+ circles, otherwise, the invited player should be in your circle. You can read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer#participants) for more details.

Comment: That is correct, thanks. However, how does this help me implement a chat function?